# Connecting YouTube Brand Accounts

Tags: youtube-api

Using the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and the ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync I am able to connect my app to a YouTube account. Personal accounts are great and I can disconnect them and reconnect them at will.

The user should be able to disconnect using the dashboard at: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions but for a brand account I'm not able to manage the connected apps, only for a personal account.

I need to disconnect to reconnect so I can get the refresh token that seems to only be given when first connecting an app.

Comment: From this [support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en), make sure that your channel is already [connected to a Brand Account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7286468). If your channel is already connected to a Brand Account: You can [add channel managers](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007). You may also refer with this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016537/youtube-apis-access-mutiple-youtube-channels-brand-accounts-using-google-adm

Comment: It appears owners can manage connected apps but managers cannot.