# YouTube API - Option for "Authorized redirect URIs" not showing on credentials page

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating an internal project application with the YouTube Data v3 API. Following the tutorial given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106136), I am trying to add "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" as a link under "Authorized redirect URIs" when editing the client_id and client_secret entry.

When I go into the console and edit the credentials, I cannot find this option anywhere. See the screenshot below to see what I see when I edit the Oauth 2.0 Client IDs.

Does anyone have an idea about why I cannot see this option or where I have to go in order to find it?

[Screenshot of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjnO3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why. It's because I had set my credentials to "Other (Windows)". When I created new credentials with "Web server" selected instead, the option started showing.