# YouTube Data API - Upload video to youtube Brand Account's channel using manager account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload videos using manager account to Brand Account's channel. I found workflow how it could be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106136/3103266). When I've tried to generate refresh token [using OAuthTokenGenerator](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/wiki/Using-OAuthTokenGenerator) I've got an error **"This client is restricted to users within its organization."**. Need to mention that we have requirement for our client to be internal so we can't make it external.

I found that our Brand Account's primary owner email is in the different domain. We [changed](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7311601?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) our Brand Account's primary owner to be within our organization. But it doesn't help we still receiving the same error "This client is restricted to users within its organization." What else should be done to solve this issue?

Comment: I tried to use our brand account youtube analytics API, and wasn't able to do so. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106136/9974143) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

Apparently there is no way to link a YouTube Brand Account to GSuite which means you will never be able to authenticate the YouTube API **with Application Type = Internal**, as a Brand Account owner. So this is a dead end: *"Only users with a Google Account in your organization can grant access to the scopes requested by this app."*

You have three options:

Option 1: Make your OAuth app public (and clickthrough the security warning in the auth popup).

Option 2: Become a Content Partner and try the 'onBehalfOfContentOwner' param.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Option 3: Migrate your videos to a non-Brand YouTube channel over which one of your GSuite org's users has control.

Rather unfortunate that this is the way it works, especially when the email addresses could be matched by Google effortlessly (if a GSuite user is the Owner or Primary Owner of a Brand Account, they should be able to authenticate as that Brand Account to the YouTube API in **Internal App mode**).