# ERROR 403 Forbidden YouTube Analytics API

Tags: python, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to getting reports using YouTube Analytics API but **403 forbidden** stucks me. I search a lot on google but no relevant solution found. I 'm trying a code from its official docs with google oAuth 2.0 .

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtubeAnalytics"
    api_version = "v2"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube_analytics = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
        dimensions="day",
        endDate="2018-12-01",
        ids="channel==UCzxqTj9GZVeSy_Er9VPvKEQ",
        metrics="views",
        startDate="2018-11-29"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
Error

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That HTTP 403 response may indicate that some part of the google account you are trying to use has not been authorized/configured properly. You may wish to go to your [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and check that you have:

[Enabled the YouTube Analytics API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com?q=search&referrer=search) for use in the project you are wanting to use it in.
Follow the [Authorization flow for the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/registering_an_application). It should be beared-in-mind that there is currently no support for accessing channel data through service accounts (but analytical data can be accessed on *behalf* of another user.)

Extract from the API (June 2021):

> - The YouTube Analytics API does not support the service account flow.
> - The YouTube Reporting API only supports the service account flow for
>   YouTube content owners that own and manage multiple YouTube channels.
>   Specifically, content owners can use service accounts in API requests
>   that set a value for the onBehalfOfContentOwner request parameter.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure you have enabled the YouTube Analytics API for use in the project...

If you are still getting the error, it might be because:

1. You didn't add yourself as a test user in the Google Cloud Project --> OAuth consent screen
2. You are trying to access your brand account analytics, and not your own channel analitycs.
   In this case, [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106136/9974143) solved the problem for me.