# Internal Use of YouTube API Oauth does not allow Brand Account [youtube-data-api]

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a desktop application that uses OAuth2 for our internal users to upload customer videos to our YouTube Channel. When setting the OAuth Consent to INTERNAL, we recieve an error when trying to used our Brand Account YouTube Channel.

The Brand account was created and is owned by an Internal user to the domain.

The error is 403 Org_Internal.

Error 403: org_internal
This client is restricted to users within its organization.
Request Details
The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
access_type: offline
response_type: code
redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:50580/authorize/
client_id: 750557968923-bf1tpfstuloo4st2jd6vpr9uc2ij5vp2.apps.googleusercontent.com
scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

Stack Overflow has several similar question with no resolutions yet.

[youtube-data-api]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106136/9974143) might help or [this one](https://gist.github.com/veuncent/e0b831ab41d598961d2656c7fc5cc0f9)