# Youtube analytics API 403 error brand account

Tags: python, youtube-api, http-status-code-403, account, youtube-analytics-api

I've tried running the analytics/reporting APIs with my main account (using my local machine's terminal to run python scripts from the [YT API Github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/07263305b59a7c3275bc7e925f9ce6cabf774022/python/yt_analytics_report.py)), and came up with my brand accounts, I end up with an error 403 org_internal when trying to authorize via OAuth authentication flow.

I've also tried following the steps laid out here:

[YouTube APIs - Access mutiple youtube channels (Brand Accounts) using Google Admin account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016537/youtube-apis-access-mutiple-youtube-channels-brand-accounts-using-google-adm?rq=1)

Once I get to step 6, I get the following error:

[error 403 org_internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DarG8.png)

and of course the request details are all fulfilled; there shouldn't be a problem with authorization (I'm not using a service account), scopes, etc...

I can use my main account for the API authorization.

2nd edit: Here is the OAuth query with the parameters I'm using: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix_params=%7B%22dimensions%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222022-04-30%22%2C%22ids%22%3A%22channel%3D%3DMINE%22%2C%22metrics%22%3A%22estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222022-03-31%22%7D

Comment: "I can use at least my main account for the API authorization..." Does this mean you have successfully used API explorer and returned output ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query )? I have no idea what the issue is but for that error, try going to `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` (where "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" is the name of your project) and make your publishing status "Testing" and user type "External" or (also try "Internal"). I can't remember but you may need to also add your e-mail as a "Test User".

Comment: I added the OAuth explorer query I'm using, and tried your suggestions, but I'm still getting this error

Comment: Any  ideas @DavidErickson?